# Scroll FixedSizeList to last element when wrapped in AutoSizer

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I have the following working with AutoSizer, but I need the list to scroll to the last element after loading, and therefore tried getting a ref to the FixedSizeList to no avail.

I have looked into using forward refs and a HOC using FixedSizeList outerElementType prop, but I cannot figure out how to use it correctly for this purpose.

```
const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
  <div className={index % 2 ? "ListItemOdd" : "ListItemEven"} style={style}>
    Row {index}
  </div>
);

const Example = () => {
  const listRef = createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    //The ref is always null
    if (listRef != null && listRef.current != null) {
      listRef.current.scrollToItem(1000);
    }
  }, [listRef]);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "80vh" }}>
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <FixedSizeList
            ref={listRef}
            className="List"
            height={height}
            width={width}
            itemCount={1000}
            itemSize={35}
          >
            {Row}
          </FixedSizeList>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you i'd put an id on your `div` for example `` id={`fixed-size-row-${index}`} `` then use make a function where you provide the id:

```
const scrollToEl = (index) => {
  const el = document.getElementById(`fixed-size-row-${index}`);
  el.scrollIntoView();
}
```